# Python skip first line of multiline string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, multiline

Is there a way to skip the first line of a multiline string? So that I can do this:

```
str = """
  some
  indented
  stuff"""
```

instead of

```
str = """  some
  indented
  stuff"""
```

Comment: Avoid using python built-in keywords as variable names (like `str`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python parser takes any end-of-line `\` in the code followed by no characters as a line break **for the parser**:

```
x = """\
  some
  indented
  stuff"""
```

Answer (score -1):

```python
str = """   some   indented   stuff"""

def formatter(my_str):
    return '\n'.join([elem.strip() for elem in my_str.split('\n')[1:]])     

print(formatter(str))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.